# Keras data augmentation layers in model or out of model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

How exactly do the preprocessing layers in keras work, especially in the context of as a part of the model itself? This being compared to preprocessing being applied outside the model then inputting the results for training.

I'm trying to understand running data augmentation in keras models. Lets say I have 1000 images for training. Out of model I can apply augmentation 10x and get 10000 resultant images for training.

But I don't understand what's happening when you use a preprocess layer for augmentation. Does this (or these if you use many) layers take each image and apply the transformations before training? Does this mean the total number of images used for training (and validation I assume) to be the number of epochs*the original number of images?

Is one option better than the other? Does that depend on the number of images one originally has before augmentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of preprocessing layers is that the model is truly end-to-end, i.e. raw data comes in and a prediction comes out. It makes your model portable since the preprocessing procedure is included in the SavedModel.

However, it will run everything on the GPU. Usually it makes sense to load the data using CPU worker(s) in the background while the GPU optimizes the model.

Alternatively, you could use a preprocessing layer outside of the model and inside a Dataset. The benefit of that is that you can easily create an inference-only model including the layers, which then gives you the portability at inference time but still the speedup during training.

For more information, see the [Keras guide](https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/).

Comment: Okay I understand. What I still can't figure out is what's happening with the data augmentation if I put it as a preprocessing layer inside the model. Does it take my original images and generate a new batch every epoch? Does it augment the images once (or multiple times) then train?

Comment: No batching happens before - for example, `keras.Model.fit` allows passing a batch size. The data flow is still per batch, but with preprocessing layers your raw data comes in instead of preprocessed. Also, the preprocessing layers can generate multiple channels though, depending on how you set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. Essentially there are two recommended ways of applying augmentation:

1. To the model pipeline. Here, the initial layers will be the augmentation and the latter layers the neural network.

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(512,512,3)),
        tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1/255.0),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='valid', activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

In this method, the number of images **remains the same** as before. Augmenting changes the image style, but each layer only runs once per image. I couldn't find any concrete documentation for it, but creating a model only consisting of augmentation proved the same.

```
augmentation_layer = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=0.5)])

nrows = 4
ncols = 4

fig = plt.gcf()
for images, labels in training_set.as_numpy_iterator():
    augmented_images = augmentation_layer(images)
    break
    
for i, image in enumerate(augmented_images):
    sp = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i+1)
    plt.imshow(image/255.0)
    plt.suptitle('Augmented Images') 

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    sp = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i+1)
    plt.imshow(image/255.0)
    plt.suptitle('Actual Images')
```

PS: The `training_set` is a `_PrefetchDataset` created from `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`. You may have to edit the code to get it to work with your dataset.

The results show that for each actual image, only one transformation is applied.

This method is great if you have lots of data and so do not need to increase the dataset size. If however, you wish to create additional data, then option 2 is better:

2. Applying augmentation before and then adding it into the model. In this case, you will need to run the augmentation multiple times on the same image, using a loop. You can keep adding the augmented images back to the source dataset.